# one radio group depends on another for its outcome

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

first post.. graphics person becoming a coder here. (Coding is more fun, but harder!)

2 radio groups each with 2 buttons. I have got it working where if either #client or #agent is selected from Radio 1, and #companyClient is selected from radio 2, the result is the text fields beneath the radio groups stay Readonly except #companyName. I also have it working where if #agent is selected from Radio 1, and #individualClient is selected from radio 2, the result is the text fields beneath the radio groups become editable to collect input except #companyName which stays Readonly.

What I need though is if #client is selected from Radio 1, and #individualClient is selected from radio 2, the text fields beneath the radio groups (except #companyName) stay Readonly; currently they are editable which I don't want. And I need to copy the text field values from #firstnameContact, #lastnameContact, and titleContact to them (ie to firstnameClient, lastnameClient and titleClient).

Thanks

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#companyClient, #individualClient").change(function(){
        $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient, #companyName").val("").attr("readonly",true);
        if($("#individualClient").is(":checked")){
            $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#companyName").attr("readonly");
            $("#firstnameClient").focus();
        }
        else if($("#companyClient").is(":checked")){            
            $("#companyName").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#companyName").focus();   
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<label for="firstnameContact">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstnameContact" id="firstnameContact" />

<label for="lastnameContact">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastnameContact" id="lastnameContact" />

<label for="titleContact">Title</label></div>
<input type="text" name="titleContact" id="titleContact" />

<!--Radio 1 -->
<label>Your Status</label>
<input type="radio" name="yourStatus" id="client" value="client" checked />
<label for="client">I am the Client</label>
<input type="radio" name="yourStatus" id="agent" value="agent" />
<label for="agent">I am an Agent</label></div>

<!--Radio 2 -->
<label>select one:</label>
<input type="radio" name="clientType" id="companyClient" value="companyClient" />
<label for="companyClient">Company</label>
<input type="radio" name="clientType" id="individualClient" value="individualClient" />
<label for="individualClient">Individual</label>    

<label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" readonly />

<label for="firstnameClient">First Name</label></div>
<input type="text" name="firstnameClient" id="firstnameClient" readonly />

<label for="lastnameClient">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastnameClient" id="lastnameClient" readonly />

<label for="titleClient">Title</label></div>
<input type="text" name="titleClient" id="titleClient" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added a form around all elements and made the change on it, seems to works.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgukwcst/)

```
$(function(){
    $("form").change(function(){
        $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient, #companyName").val("").attr("readonly",true);
        if($("#individualClient").is(":checked")){
            $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#companyName").attr("readonly");
            $("#firstnameClient").focus();
        }
        else if($("#companyClient").is(":checked")){            
            $("#companyName").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#companyName").focus();   
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Or you can use `disabled` to make it more clear for users.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgukwcst/6/)

```
$(function(){
    $("form").change(function(){
        $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient, #companyName").val("").prop("disabled",true);
        if($("#individualClient").is(":checked")){
            $("#firstnameClient, #lastnameClient, #titleClient").removeProp("disabled");
            $("#companyName").prop("disabled",true);
            $("#firstnameClient").focus();
        }
        else if($("#companyClient").is(":checked")){            
            $("#companyName").removeProp("disabled");
            $("#companyName").focus();   
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, you can add a PHP validation and test of all fields to make it safier and better.

Comment: hi Vincent thanks for taking the time to check. I've since looked at my setup and it's unnecessarily complicated and I can see I am a beginner at this. Already I'm starting to find the less page interactivity the better. It seems to hinder back end development which is more important.

Comment: I add an other alternative to readonly. It's not perfect and you surely have to change some conditions in your code to make it works better but it is an other way to continue this :)